# How to access array fields in FirebaseFirestore w/Android Studio/Kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of objects in my Cloud Firestore database called Experience. Each experience has a `username`, `date`, etc. and there can be multiple experiences in Experience list. How can I access particular fields of my Experience array? I know that in, let's say, Dart, I can type something like:

```
querySnapshot.documents[i].data["Experience"][number of array item]["username"]
```

But how can I do the same thing in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an array of custom (Experience) objects into a Cloud Firestore database, it will be added to the database as a List. If your database looks similar to:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- myCollection (collection)
          |
          --- myDocument (document)
                |
                --- experiences (array)
                       |
                       --- 0 (Experience object)
                       |   |
                       |   --- username: "UserName"
                       |   |
                       |   --- date: May 25, 2019 at 12:12:12 PM UTC+3
                       |
                       --- 1 (Experience object)
                           |
                           --- username: "AnotherUserName"
                           |
                           --- date: May 24, 2019 at 13:13:13 PM UTC+3
```

Please note that currently it is not possible to get a List of custom (Experience) objects by simply getting the data from the `experiences` property. When using:

```
List<Object> list = (List<Object>) document.get("experiences");
Object item = list.get(yourIndex);
```

The `item` object is actually a `HashMap` and not an `Experience` object. I wrote the above lines of code in Java, so you can see the return type more clearly. So a line like the following:

```
val experience: Experience = (list[yourIndex] as Experience).username
```

Will not work. If you try to cast that `HashMap` to a `Experience` object, you'll get an error that looks like this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.Experience

So to solve this, you'll have to write your own code, that can help you convert a `HashMap` object to an `Experience` object. Further more, if you need a `List<Experience>`, you'll also need to convert the `List<HashMap>` objects to a `List<Experience>` objects.

Answer (score 0):

List type fields arrive as List type objects in Java/Kotlin.  You work with it just like you would any other List in your language of choice.

```
List<Object> list = List<Object> snapshot.get("list-type-field");
Object item = list.get(index_of_your_choice);
// then check its type and cast it
```

You should familiarize yourself with [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) and the [general documentation for querying Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).